# Proper way to get swift dictionary item index

Tags: ios, swift

I have dictionary in my app written in Swift

```
var cities: [String: String] = ["":"not specified", "ny":"New York", "la":"Los Angeles", "sf":"San Francisco"]
```

I use this dictionary to build pickerView. When user selects one of this items - city code is saving to device memory.

When user opens app next time I want pickerView to show saved city. How should i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the index of a key in a dictionary with higher-order functions:

```
let desiredKey = "ny"
let pos = x.enumerate().filter { (pair: (index: Int, element: (String, String))) -> Bool in
    return pair.element.0 == desiredKey
}.map { (pair: (index: Int, element: (String, String))) -> Int in
    return pair.index
}
```

`pos` is an `Optional(Int)` containing the position of `"ny"` in the current iteration order of the dictionary.

Store the value of the key somewhere (say, in user defaults), then retrieve it, get the index of the key-value pair using the code above, and pass to `selectedRowInComponent:` of your picker view.

**Note:** The problem with using a dictionary alone as a backing for your picker is that the order is not specified explicitly. Adding or removing keys may change the order of existing keys. In addition, existing keys may not end up in places that you want them to be - for example, your `"" - "not specified"` pair may end up in the middle of the picker.

To fix this problem, keep a separate array of city keys in the proper order that you wish to follow. Use this array to decide the picker row in which a city is to be displayed, and look up the actual city using the dictionary.

Comment: You can simply use `let index = cities.indexForKey("ny")` to obtain a `DictionaryIndex`

Comment: @bpds `DictionaryIndex` is not the kind of index I could use to set the row of my picker view, unless I am missing something.

Comment: The question of @moonvader seems to be about persistency. If so the goal is to store the key not the key position.

Comment: @bpds I read his question differently - mostly, because of the title.

Comment: You can access to an `DictionaryIndex position by calling ```index.distanceTo(cities.startIndex)``` But the normal way to access a Dictionary is to use the subscript ```dictionary[key]```  in this sample the key type a string. In this context the "index" is a String.

Comment: @bpds It does not look like OP wants to access the dictionary. To me, it looks like he is trying to set picker view to show the city. Since picker views go by integer position, not by dictionary keys, I think OP needs an int position from a dictionary key.

Comment: I really want to get item index as int number)

Comment: @moonvader Great then - that's what the code above is doing, give it a try and see if it does what you want it to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use NSUserDefaults to insure the persistency of your cityCode.

Copy an paste this sample in a playground.

```
var cities: [String: String] = ["":"not specified", "ny":"New York", "la":"Los Angeles", "sf":"San Francisco"]

let cityCodeIndexKey="cityCodeIndexKey"

/**
 Selects and saves the cityCode

 - parameter cityCode: a cityCode String

 - returns: true if the code exists.
 */
func selectCity(cityCode:String)->Bool{
    if let  _ = cities.indexForKey(cityCode){
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(cityCode, forKey:cityCodeIndexKey)
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
        return true
    }else{
        return false
    }
}

selectCity("ny") // Returns true
selectCity("pr") // Returns false

NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey(cityCodeIndexKey) // returns "ny"
```

Answer (score 0):

Get key,

var cityLongName <- user selected one

```
var key = dict.first((key,value) In{
If (value == cityLongName ){
 return true
}else{
return false
} 
}).key!
```

Get values ,

```
var value = dict[“city sort name”]
```